# Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte allocation with 7913456 free bytes and 7MB until OOM... target footpring ...growth limit

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-video, react-native-image-picker

I am using React Native to develop an app. I get an error when trying to upload a video more than 20 sec. The code works fine for small videos.

```
const response = await fetch(videoPicker)
    const blob = await response.blob()
    const path = `video/${moment().format('YYYYMMDD')}/${uuidv4()}.mp4`
    Storage.put(path, blob, {
      progressCallback(progress) {
        setProgress((progress.loaded / progress.total * 100).toFixed(0))
        console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);
      }
    })
```

I tried android:hardwareAccelerated="false" and android:largeHeap="true". I think it helped. But not much.

Here is a screenshot for more illustration.[image]

Comment: Could you try adding `"start-max": "node --max-old-space-size=16000 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"` to your `package.json` under scripts and then running the app using `npm start-max`?

Comment: Did not work :(